# Eagle CAD autorouter places tracks too close to vias

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, cad, autorouter

Eagle CAD autorouter places tracks too close to vias. I tried to change some parameters in the design rules but without a good result.

[image: PCB]

Comment: Which ones are too close? I don't see any problems.

Comment: With those few traces (shown) why auto-route?

Comment: I see two component pads there, but no vias.  Don''t see any clearance problems. (but I would like a little more lead length on those through-hole resistors)

Comment: How is the "trace to pad" clearance a problem and "trace to poly" not?

Answer (score 3):

If you think the tracks are 'too close' to the vias, in a way that will cause actual problems, then there is a problem with your design rule configuration.

However, if your issue is just that there is no *reason* for the tracks to run so close to the vias, and a sensible person routing them would have chosen differently: Yes, welcome to the autorouter. My understanding is that professionals never use it, but always do routing themselves. I've honestly never heard anybody suggest that using it is anything but a bad idea. I would recommend that you practice doing the routing yourself, instead; you'll get better results.

Comment: It's just the autorouter solves a problem I never had during routing. If it was able to align impedance-matched pairs, bundle these pairs to buses, nicely route and length-match them, hell, yes, I would like that. But bummer – no such function.